# Getting 404 Not Found Error When Uploading Image to Express.js Backend

Tags: node.js, angular, flutter, express, http-status-code-404

Description:

I'm developing an Angular admin panel that allows users to upload images to my Express.js backend. However, I'm encountering a "404 Not Found" error when trying to upload an image to the server.

Here's the scenario and the relevant code snippets:

1. **Angular Admin Panel (Frontend)**:

   - I have an image upload feature in my Angular admin panel.
   - When a user selects an image and clicks the upload button, a POST request is made to the backend to upload the image.
2. Server.js

   ```
   const express = require('express');
   const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
   const cors = require('cors');
   const path = require('path'); // Add this import
   const initializeSocket = require('./socket.js');
   const mongoose = require('mongoose'); // Import Mongoose
   const app = express();
   // Set up CORS configuration
   const corsOptions = {
     origin: 'http://localhost:4200', 
     methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
     credentials: true,
     optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
   };
   app.use(cors(corsOptions));

   app.use(bodyParser.json());

   // Initialize Mongoose and connect to the database
   const uri = 'mongodb+srv://mongodb.net/?retryWrites='; 
   mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

   const db = mongoose.connection;
   db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'Connection error:'));
   db.once('open', () => {
     console.log('Connected to the database');
   });

   // Simulated user credentials (replace with your database logic)
   const adminCredentials = {
     email: 'in',
     password: '23'
   };

   app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
     const { email, password } = req.body;

     console.log('Received credentials:', email, password);

     if (email === adminCredentials.email && password === adminCredentials.password) {
       res.status(200).json({ message: 'Login successful' });
     } else {
       console.log('Invalid credentials:', email, password);
       res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid credentials' });
     }
   });


   const imageUploadRouter = require('./imageUpload.js');
   app.use("/upload", imageUploadRouter);


   app.use('/images', express.static('images'));


   const http = require('http');
   const server = http.createServer(app);

   const socketIo = require('./socket.js');
   const io = socketIo(server);


   // Handle 404 routes
   app.use((_req, res, _next) => {
     res.status(404).json({ message: 'Route not found' });
   });

   server.listen(3000, () => {
     console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
   });
   ```
3. **Issue**:

   - When I try to upload an image, I receive a "404 Not Found" error.
   - The Angular frontend is making a POST request to **`http://localhost:3000/upload`**, but the server seems unable to handle this route properly.
4. **What I've Tried**:

   - I've double-checked the route URL and HTTP method in the frontend code. It matches the route **`/upload`** and uses POST, which corresponds to the route defined in the backend.
   - I've also ensured that the server is running and listening on port 3000.
   - I've restarted the server and cleared cache to rule out any caching issues.
   - The catch-all route (**`app.use((req, res, next) => {...})`**) seems to be configured correctly to handle undefined routes.
5. **Expected Outcome**:

   - I expect the image upload to work without any "404 Not Found" errors.

Comment: Are you developing for Flutter Web, or mobile, desktop? You don't show your Dart code (where you are presumably getting the 404). If Flutter Web, update the question showing the Developer Tools > Network tab of Chrome showing the 404.

Comment: Im Developing for Flutter Mobile App & what i exactly doing is that in my flutter app have carousel slider so inside showing the image first i implemented a socket.io client side & server side in my backend server & in this flutter app & i'm uploading the image from my admin panel banner screen which can control these kind of all things so the image will upload through the banner screen admin & the image will send to backend the backend will transfer the image realtime in our carousel slider but getting this error
http://localhost:3000/upload
Request Method
GET
Status Code
404 Not Found

Comment: But in Flutter mobile, `localhost` refers to the phone itself (which obviously isn't running the server) - change to the IP address of the laptop or actual server device. For the Android emulator, search how to refer to the hosting PC from the emulator (something like 10.0.0.2)